# How to format an argument inside a function but also print the string as many times as the argument

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, function, formatting

I am a beginner and was just messing around with functions and i thought of the code below. I want to print the strings as many times as whatever the value of a is going to be, but i also want to format the value of the argument a inside the string. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
def vhf(a):
    print "So i want this times %d "*a % a

vhf(5)
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 4, in <module>
    vhf(5)
  File "p.py", line 2, in vhf
    print "...So i want this times %d "*a % a
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you multiply the string by a, the number of format arguments needed is multiplied by a. You can move the multiplication to AFTER the formatting to fix your issue.

```
def vhf(a):
    print "So i want this times %d " % a * a

vhf(5)
```